# Is there a way to create methods just for the instance of a Ruby class from inside that instance?

Tags: ruby

Let there be `class Example` defined as:

```
class Example
  def initialize(test='hey')
    self.class.send(:define_method, :say_hello, lambda { test })
  end
end
```

On calling `Example.new; Example.new` I get a `warning: method redefined; discarding old say_hello`. This, I conclude, must be because it defines a method in the actual class (which makes sense, from the syntax). And that, of course, would prove disastrous should there be multiple instances of `Example` with different values in their methods.

Is there a way to create methods just for the instance of a class from inside that instance?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to grab a reference to the instance's singleton class, the class that holds all the instance specific stuff, and define the method on it. In ruby 1.8, it looks a little messy. (if you find a cleaner solution let me know!)

**Ruby 1.8**

```
class Example
  def initialize(test='hey')
    singleton = class << self; self end
    singleton.send :define_method, :say_hello, lambda { test }
  end
end
```

Ruby 1.9 however, provides a much easier way in.

**Ruby 1.9**

```
class Example
  def initialize(test='hey')
    define_singleton_method :say_hello, lambda { test }
  end
end
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to use the term `singleton class` as it is the official name. Indeed, Ruby 1.9.2 introduces `Object#singleton_class`

Comment: @Marc: Oh nice. Haven't had much time to play with 1.9.2 yet.  I'm glad someone finally settled on a name though.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Rather than get define the method on the instance's singleton class, how would you normally define it on the class?. i.e.. `class Foo; def bar; end; end` - how would you  define a method like `bar` instead of defining it on the singleton class?

Answer (score 40):

First off, a small style tip:

```
self.class.send(:define_method, :say_hello, lambda { test })
```

You can make this look a little bit nicer by using the new proc literal in Ruby 1.9:

```
self.class.send(:define_method, :say_hello, -> { test })
```

But you don't need that. Ruby has something called *blocks*, which are basically a piece of code that you can pass as an argument to a method. In fact, you already used blocks, since `lambda` is just a method which takes a block as an argument and returns a `Proc`. However, `define_method` *already* takes a block anyway, there is no need to pass a block to `lambda` which converts it to a `Proc` which it passes to `define_method` which then converts it back into a block:

```
self.class.send(:define_method, :say_hello) { test }
```

As you already noticed, you are defining the method on the wrong class. You are defining it on the `Example` class, since inside an instance method like `initialize`, `self` is the current object (i.e. `ex1` or `ex2` in @mikej's example), which means that `self.class` is `ex1`'s class, which is `Example`. So, you are overwriting the same method over and over again.

This leads to the following unwanted behavior:

```
ex1 = Example.new('ex1')
ex2 = Example.new('ex2') # warning: method redefined; discarding old say_hello
ex1.say_hello            # => ex2 # Huh?!?
```

Instead, if you want a singleton method, you need to define it on the singleton class:

```
(class << self; self end).send(:define_method, :say_hello) { test }
```

This works as intended:

```
ex1 = Example.new('ex1')
ex2 = Example.new('ex2')
ex1.say_hello            # => ex1
ex2.say_hello            # => ex2
```

In Ruby 1.9, there's a method that does that:

```
define_singleton_method(:say_hello) { test }
```

Now, this works the way you want it to, but there's a higher-level problem here: this is not Ruby code. It is Ruby *syntax*, but it's not Ruby code, it's Scheme.

Now, Scheme is a *brilliant* language and writing Scheme code in Ruby syntax is certainly not a bad thing to do. It beats the hell out of writing Java or PHP code in Ruby syntax, or, as was the case in a StackOverflow question yesterday, Fortran-57 code in Ruby syntax. But it's not as good as writing *Ruby* code in Ruby syntax.

Scheme is a functional language. Functional languages use functions (more precisely, function closures) for encapsulation and state. But Ruby is not a functional language, it is an object-oriented language and OO languages use *objects* for encapsulation and state.

So, function closures become objects and captured variables become instance variables.

We can also come at this from a completely different angle: what you are doing is that you are defining a *singleton* method, which is a method whose purpose it is to define behavior which is specific to *one* object. But you are defining that singleton method for *every* instance of the class, and you are defining the *same* singleton method for every instance of the class. We already have a mechanism for defining behavior for every instance of a class: instance methods.

Both of these arguments come from completely opposite directions, but they arrive at the same destination:

```
class Example
  def initialize(test='hey')
    @test = test
  end

  def say_hello
    @test
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

I know it was asked two years back, but I would like to add one more answer. `.instance_eval` will help to add methods to instance object

```
    string = "String"
    string.instance_eval do
      def new_method
        self.reverse
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Define instance method from outside:

```
example = Example.new
def example.say_hello
  puts 'hello'
end
```

From inside:

```
class Example
  def initialize(word='hey')
    @word = word
    def self.say_hello
      puts "example: #{@word}"
    end
  end
end
```

Tested on ruby 2.5